# Jmeter Regex to match for date of the format dd/mm/yyyy using "\d"

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a data which looks like

```
EX:992215:SHOW:CMS016:000335:ESP:15:EUR:Euro:4:14:01/05/2009‌​:30/04/2017:52:26:
```

I wanted to read the last value i.e 26 using jmeter regular expression extractor. I tried with the following regex,

```
.+:992215:.+:.+:\d+:.+:.+:.+:.+:\d+:\d+:\d+/\d+/\d+:\d+/\d+/\d+:\d:(.+?):
```

The regex is not working from `\d+/\d+/\d+:\d+/\d+/\d+:\d:(.+?):` which is the date part. Can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: Try just `:992215:.*:(\d+)` with  `$1$` template. If you say [*i want to extract other values in the data*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285884/jmeter-regex-to-match-for-date-of-the-format-dd-mm-yyyy-using-d#comment65906138_39285933) you must include that in the question. If you want to use your own regex, what you might try is to replace all `.+` with `[^:]+`

Comment: Moreover, your string has no `992215`, did you mean `000335`?

Comment: Try [`:000335:[^:]+:\d+:[^:]+:[^:]+:\d+:\d+:\d+/\d+/\d+:\d+/\d+/\d+:\d+:([^:]+):`](https://regex101.com/r/qT7oI0/1)

Comment: Thank you Wiktor :) It is working now.

Comment: The data is  EX:992215:SHOW:CMS016:000335:ESP:15:EUR:Euro:4:14:01/05/2009:30/04/2017:52:26:, and  ":992215:.*:(\d+)"  worked.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how can i extract "01/05/2009" i.e. date after "Euro:4:14:"

Comment: @ValarDohaeris Perhaps, [`Euro:\d+:\d+:([^:]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qT7oI0/3) will do. Or [`Euro:.*?(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/qT7oI0/4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not care what is between `:992215:` and the number after the last `:` on the line, use

```
:992215:.*:(\d+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT7oI0/2)

**Details**:

- `:992215:` - a literal string
- `.*:` - any 0+  characters other than a newline up to the last `:` on the line
- `(\d+)` - Group `$1$` capturing 1+ digits.

If you want to use your own regex, what you might try is to replace all `.+` (that is, the greedy dot pattern matching any 1+ characters other than a newline as many as possible) with `[^:]+` (a negated character class matching 1+ chars other than `:` as many as possible).